# Particular workstations cannot reach specific servers in an openvpn site2site environment

Tags: openvpn, site-to-site-vpn

It seems to be a weird problem to me. Here is the situation. I set up a site to site environment by openvpn (udp protocol), most servers and workstations can reach the other site but several servers failed. My environment is below,

Site A

```
Subnet 192.168.11.0/24
Gateway to Internet: 192.168.11.1
OpenVpn server: 192.168.11.211(LAN), 10.0.0.11(tun)
```

Site B,

```
Subnet 192.168.1.0/24
Gateway to Internet: 192.168.1.1
OpenVPN server: 192.168.1.211(LAN), 10.0.0.1(tun)
```

Most servers can reach the other site. e.g. 
I ran ping from my workstation 192.168.11.103 and I can reach 192.168.1.60

```
PING 192.168.1.60 (192.168.1.60): 56 data bytes
92 bytes from 192.168.11.1: Redirect Host(New addr: 192.168.11.211)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 0054 27df   0 0000  40  01 c4d6 192.168.11.103  192.168.1.60 
64 bytes from 192.168.1.60: icmp_seq=0 ttl=62 time=50.677 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.60: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=46.558 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.60: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=25.199 ms
```

However, I cannot reach 192.168.1.61

```
PING 192.168.1.61 (192.168.1.61): 56 data bytes
92 bytes from 192.168.11.1: Redirect Host(New addr: 192.168.11.211)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 0054 722c   0 0000  40  01 7a88 192.168.11.103  192.168.1.61 
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

I definitely set static route on 192.168.1.61

```
 192.168.11.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.1.211       1
```

and I can even ping back from 192.168.1.61

```
>ping 192.168.11.103
正在 Ping 192.168.11.103 具有 32 字节的数据:
来自 192.168.11.103 的回复: 字节=32 时间=114ms TTL=62
来自 192.168.11.103 的回复: 字节=32 时间=102ms TTL=61
来自 192.168.11.103 的回复: 字节=32 时间=102ms TTL=61
来自 192.168.11.103 的回复: 字节=32 时间=23ms TTL=61
```

Please bear with me that my server runs on a Chinese version OS.

I run trace route on both ends and got the followings

```
$ traceroute 192.168.1.60 //weird, you can see above that this server can be reached by ping. 
traceroute to 192.168.1.60 (192.168.1.60), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.11.1 (192.168.11.1)  1.931 ms  1.858 ms  2.591 ms
 2  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  25.274 ms  23.538 ms  23.927 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
//truncated.
```

while for the server I cannot reach, I got the same response on traceroute.

```
traceroute 192.168.1.61
traceroute to 192.168.1.61 (192.168.1.61), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.11.1 (192.168.11.1)  3.193 ms  2.823 ms  1.988 ms
 2  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  24.394 ms *  23.029 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
//truncated.
```

I decided to see another server I can reach (`64 bytes from 192.168.1.30: icmp_seq=13339 ttl=126 time=65.530 ms`) and got the perfect response.

```
traceroute 192.168.1.30
traceroute to 192.168.1.30 (192.168.1.30), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.11.1 (192.168.11.1)  6.746 ms  1.813 ms  2.417 ms
 2  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  22.344 ms  22.521 ms  23.538 ms
 3  192.168.1.30 (192.168.1.30)  22.876 ms *  102.062 ms
```

Cause I can ping back from 192.168.1.61, I also did a tracert and the response is good to me.

```
>tracert 192.168.11.103
通过最多 30 个跃点跟踪
到 mymachine [192.168.11.103] 的路由:
  1    <1 毫秒   <1 毫秒   <1 毫秒 192.168.1.211
  2    20 ms    21 ms    20 ms  10.0.0.11
  3    23 ms    26 ms    24 ms  mymachine [192.168.11.103]
跟踪完成。
```

As I mentioned above, servers and workstations can reach most serves on the other site but it happened to specific servers. In this case, I think most problems are related to 192.168.1.60 and 192.168.1.61. However, I cannot find any difference on these two servers with others.

I compared the ifconfig and iptables on both openvpn servers, they are almost same (definitely the directions are not equal).

I'd like to seek for ideas to trouble-shoot the problem.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Regards,

Kyle

Comment: Please take a minute and format your post properly - putting terminal output in proper code blocks.

Comment: done, sorry for the improper format. please help. thanks in advance.